# JBPM - kie-maven-plugin -returns Unknown resource type: ResourceType = 'jBPM BPMN2 Language'

Tags: jbpm, kie

At this moment I'm using the latest and gratest jBPM libraries (7.74.1.Final), kie-maven-plugin (9.44.0-Final) and drools (9.44.0.Final).

I have a maven project that can generate the drools rules in a kjar.
But after I place some bpmn2 processes in de kjar my build failed with the error:
`unkown resource type: JBPM BPMN2 Language`

I have added jbpm-bpmn2 library as a dependency but still have the error. I use the bpmn2 processes from a kogito example. (orders.bpmn2, persons.bpmn2, orderItems.bpmn2) and also package the java classes that are needed for the compilation.